# How to fix :cmap breaking :cabbrev

Tags: abbreviations

I have a few :cabbrev mappings that I use frequently, like `:qq` as a shortcut for `:q!`.

Recently I installed a [nifty plugin](https://github.com/inside/vim-search-pulse) and these abbreviations no longer triggered with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, although <kbd>Space</kbd> would still activate them.  It turns out that the plugin rebinds `<CR>` in command mode to a function that does some work then returns a string `<CR>`, which is presumably interpreted as a keystroke, although I do not know why.  However, the "keystroke" is not triggering abbreviations.

Is this a Vim bug, or does the extra `<CR>` need to be triggered some other way?  I would like to keep the plugin if possible, but I really like my abbreviations.

Comment: Have you consider asking about on the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/inside/vim-search-pulse/issues)?

Comment: Note: this has [since been posted on the issue tracker by the OP](https://github.com/inside/vim-search-pulse/issues/9), and it looks like the bug got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger expansion of abbreviations by pressing `Ctrl-]`. So perhaps you can add the CTRL-] in front of the mapping of the `Enter` key.

Read the help at `:h i_CTRL-]` and `:h c_CTRL-]`

Also you should probably create an issue for that on the plugins repository.